# Deleting elements from a malloc'd array in C

Tags: c, arrays

So I have

```
int * queue;
queue = (int*)malloc(size) //size being a user variable
```

Since this is a queue, it will be a FIFO deal when deleting elements. I specifically have to use an array instead of a linked list to do this. When I delete, I just shift every number over to index-1. However, how do I get rid of the last number? So if I malloc size for a 5 element array, then input `1 3 2 4 _(nothing)` then I delete so it becomes `3 2 4 4 _`. How do I get rid of that second 4 that shouldn't be there. I want `3 2 4 _ _`. I thought I would just set `queue[last_element] = NULL` to get rid of it but that throws an "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" warning. Whats the correct way to do this then?

Comment: How are you keeping track of the number of elements in the queue?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have a `count` variable that gets increased or decreased.  So when I say `queue[last_element]` I really mean `queue[count-1]` not `queue[last_malloced_space]`. From what I can tell the actual implementation is working even with the warning, but I just wanted to know how to do this without getting a warning.

Comment: Note: do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: So, if you know the length of the queue, you already have your answer. This is an XY-problem: You are asking for a specific yolution to solve a different problem. The warning looks like something different. You'll have to post a [mcve] to get a proper answer.

Comment: @TommyK So then you have your answer. You get rid of the extra value by decrementing `count` and now the queue doesn't have that value anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it. What you want is this:

```
queue[last_element] = 0;
```

In practice `0` is equivalent to `NULL`. The error you got was because `NULL` is defined as `(void *)0`, making it a pointer.

Comment: But what if I want to add 0 as an actual value? It's a queue of ints, so 0 is an acceptable input. How would I differentiate between nothing and the user inserting 0?

Comment: Then clearly `0` will not work as a sentinel value. You saying you tried `NULL` led me to believe it would be acceptable. Is there another "impossible" value you can use? If not, then you will have to use an entirely different approach, such as maintaining a count of elements and packing the list when one is deleted.